# Numerical solving diffusion equation in spherical coordinates

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method, spherical

Mathematica nicely solves Poisson's equation in spherical coordinates as

```
eqn=Laplacian[V[r,\[Theta]],{r,\[Theta],\[Phi]},"Spherical"]==-Sin[\[Theta]];
a=1;b=10;
sol=NDSolveValue[{eqn,V[a,\[Theta]]==1,V[b,\[Theta]]==0},V,{r,a,b},{\[Theta],0,\[Pi]}];
```

but failed to solve a similar time-dependent problem

```
eqn = D[V[t, r, \[Theta]], t] == 
   Laplacian[V[t, r, \[Theta]], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"] + 
    Sin[\[Theta]];
a = 1/2; b = 1;
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, V[t, a, \[Theta]] == 1, 
    V[t, b, \[Theta]] == 0, V[0, r, \[Theta]] == (r - b)/(a - b)}, 
   V, {t, 0, 1}, {r, a, b}, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}];
```

Why does Mathematica complains for this case?

> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.

> NDSolveValue::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.

I know that the pole is a special point. However, how did Mathematica get around that in the first case?

I got the answer (see below) which means I have to call explicitly `FiniteElement`. However, I've faced with even more strange 'by default' behavior. Here they are two independent equations which can be solved without problem

```
eqn = -D[V[t, r, \[Theta]], t] + 
   Laplacian[V[t, r, \[Theta]], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"] + 
   Cos[\[Theta]];
eqn1 = -D[W[t, r, \[Theta]], t] + 
   Laplacian[W[t, r, \[Theta]], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"] + 
   Cos[\[Theta]];
a = 1/2; b = 1;
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn == 0, 
    eqn1 == NeumannValue[-W[t, r, \[Theta]]/r, r == b], 
    DirichletCondition[W[t, r, \[Theta]] == 0, r == a], 
    W[0, r, \[Theta]] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[V[t, r, \[Theta]] == 0, r == a], 
    DirichletCondition[V[t, r, \[Theta]] == 0, r == b], 
    V[0, r, \[Theta]] == 0}, {V, W}, {t, 0, 1}, {r, a, b}, {\[Theta], 
    0, \[Pi]}];
```

But if you slightly change an order of equations (`eqn == 0` moved to 4th position)

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn1 == 
     NeumannValue[-W[t, r, \[Theta]]/r, r == b], 
    DirichletCondition[W[t, r, \[Theta]] == 0, r == a], 
    W[0, r, \[Theta]] == 0, eqn == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[V[t, r, \[Theta]] == 0, r == a], 
    DirichletCondition[V[t, r, \[Theta]] == 0, r == b], 
    V[0, r, \[Theta]] == 0}, {V, W}, {t, 0, 1}, {r, a, b}, {\[Theta], 
    0, \[Pi]}];
```

then you will get an error

> LinearSolve::parpiv: Zero pivot was detected during the numerical factorization or there was a problem in the iterative refinement process. It is possible that the matrix is ill-conditioned or singular.

I'm puzzled what is a rule or it is a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your boundary conditions to `DirichletConditions`

```
eqnt = D[V[t, r, \[Theta]], t] == 
Laplacian[V[t, r, \[Theta]], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"] +Sin[\[Theta]] ;
a = 1/2; b = 1;

sol = NDSolveValue[{ eqnt, 
DirichletCondition[V[t, r, \[Theta]] == 1, r == a], 
DirichletCondition[V[t, r, \[Theta]] == 0, r == b] , 
V[0, r, \[Theta]] == (r - b)/(a - b)}, 
V, {t, 0, 1}, {r, a, b}, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}]
```

time dependeent solutions

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@Table[sol[t, r, \[Theta]], {t, {0, .1, 1  }/5}], {r,a, b}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[1], Mesh -> False]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: nice use of DirichletCondition!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, wow, it is so simple and so confusing. Thank a lot. Could you please  explain this feature?

Comment: @Nasser Thanks! The alternative `...Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}` was too long for me ;-)

Comment: @RodionStepanov Using `DirichletConditions`or `NeumannValue` forces `NDSolve` to call Finite Element solver. Instead you could get the same result if you use `NDSolve` without `DirchletCondition` and add the option `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}`

Comment: In my first example there is no FiniteElement but it works.

Comment: Try `sol["ElementMesh"]` for your first example ,  surprisingly you might see a FiniteElement Mesh.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I see that you are very well aware of how the solver works. Could you explain what are the boundary conditions  at  \[Theta]=0  \[Theta]=[\Pi]? They are not specified in above examples.

Comment: @RodionStepanov For `0<\[Theta]<Pi` you have the same boundary conditions (as defined by DirichletCondition!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, I find another problem. See updated first post. It's a disaster when you can't see the logic.